# How to do push notifications with ejabberd 19.09

Tags: ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 19.09.  It is connected to a SQL Server database backend for storage, and I am using "external script" (https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/authentication/#external-script) authentication to integrate authentication with my application. Ultimately this means that ejabberd does not have any user registration involved, our client app logs into ejabberd and our external auth script handles the authentication.  All message history is getting recorded in the database.

I would like to enable push notifications for messages in ejabberd. I'm aware of the `mod_push` module, and it is in my yml file which I think means it would technically be enabled, but I don't have any additional options set so it is really just `mod_push: {}` in the yml config.  But I have at least two questions about that - I'm not clear on how it works, as it sounds like it would interact with some sort of 3rd party push notification server - but where is that configured?  What does ejabberd send where to trigger a push notification?

I'm wondering that since we don't actually register users within ejabberd that the build-in process won't fully work.  In that case - our application does send push notifications to certain users as part of another process.  If I could intercept from ejabberd the notification to send something, I could have my own code trigger the push notification.  But how would that work?

I'm hoping to not need to do something as hacky as using a SQL trigger on the archive table to trigger a push notification; is there some sort of documentation on start to finish what push notifications in ejabberd mean, how they work, and how they can be implemented?  Or some sort of starting point?  Thanks,